# HTTPS Proxy failing because of ServicePointManager

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, servicepointmanager

I'm trying to connect through a https proxy but an exception is always caught stating that "The ServicePointManager does not support proxies of https scheme".
The code I'm using to test the connection is the following one :

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = new WebProxy("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443") {Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password)}
        };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var x = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org/?format=text");
        }
```

I also tested the proxy using curl and it worked perfectly (although I had to use --proxy-insecure for some reason). The command I used is :

```
    curl --proxy-insecure -x https://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 https://api.ipify.org/?format=text
```

When I tried using http:// for the proxy curl just gave me the error "(56) Proxy CONNECT aborted".

So, is it possible to use a https proxy with the .NET Framework ? (I'm currently using .NET 4.6.2)